# How to change jquery Flexslider arrows design?

Tags: jquery, flexslider, arrows

i am trying to change   Flexslider arrows design from css file, but failed. 
i am giving screenshot of what i did  and wat i wanted :D 
or is there any way to change  flexslider icon or font? 
this is my work:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fgcU.png
this is i want to do : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhxqI.png

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Previous"><span class="icon icon-arrow-left8"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Next"><span class="icon icon-arrow-right8"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't use font awesome icons ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to touch font or add a new font containing icons matching your design,
You can achieve something similar by overriding the css:

```
.flex-direction-nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -20px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
    font-family: "flexslider-icon";
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '\f001';
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    line-height: 40px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right: -50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: I tried this and it's working. But the circle looks like oblong and not circle. Can you help please.

Comment: Amazing, perfect solution that took 5 seconds to implement

Answer (score 2):

You can use fontawesome insteed flexslider font, modifying css such this example:

```css
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f053';
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: '\f054';
}
```

naturaly you must set:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

first of all